# How to locate index in AEM 6.2

Tags: lucene, adobe, aem, query-builder

How to confirm if these users in section1 (/home/users/section1) got added to the AEM index?

I created a query builder that returns all users under section 1 but how can I know if those users got added to AEM index, or is there a better way. What exactly am I looking for in the query builder that tells me they are indexed in AEM?

```
curl -s -u username:password http://localhost:4502/bin/querybuilder.json?path=/home/users/section1&jcr:primaryType=rep:AuthorizableFolder&1_property=jcr:createdBy&1_property.value=admin&1_property.operation=like&p.limit=-1
```

My return query:

success":true,"results":57654,"total":57654,"more":false,"offset":0,"hits":[{"path":"/home/users/section1/useremail1@hotmail.com","excerpt":"","name":"useremail1@hotmail.com","title":"useremail1@hotmail.com","lastModified":"2017-09-09 14:59:23","created":"2017-09-26 03:03:07"}, ....etc

Answer (score 0):

For users node, there is a OOTB index located at /oak:index/users.  It's a lucene type of index and will index all rep:Users nodes. For the lucene index, you may browse the index content with a GUI tool called Luke.

For completeness of the solution, here is a high level guide based on the assumptions above. Hope it helps.

1. Locate the physical index file (looking for /oak:index/users)
   localhost:4502/system/console/jmx/org.apache.jackrabbit.oak%3Aname%3DIndexCopier+support+statistics%2Ctype%3DIndexCopierStats
2. Download the lucene codec that corresponds to your oak version

   I built the oak-lucene-xxx.jar from Oak project (https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit-oak/tags)
3. Download and run Luke (https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/query/lucene.html#luke)
4. In Luke, go to Documents tab and Browse by term :path (quick tip: you can just type /home/users/section1 and hit enter)